# The popularity of the word "coeval" has been declining for over 100 years now. Why?

Tags: latin, archaicisms, cranberry-morphemes

According to Ngram, anyway.

The vast majority of English speakers seem to have no idea what the word means.

Now why is that?

UPDATE: After reading some of the responses:

As a **noun**.

Comment: Words become obsolete all the time, and I can't imagine that *coeval* was ever *le mot du jour*.

Comment: **Coacervate** is also undergoing a slow, grim decline, after peaking in 1949: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=coacervate&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccoacervate%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Hi, Ricky. Words fall out of usage all the time. How would this word be used in a modern context? Can you imagine saying that Captain America was [_coeval_](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/coeval)  with Adolph Hitler?

Comment: How is this question not just "primarily" but **wholly** opinion-based? (I haven't closed it unilaterally because I appreciate that there may be an answer to this supplementary question.)

Comment: When you read it you think it means "co-evaluate".  When you hear it you think it means "equally evil".  It's simply not a reasonable word.

Comment: @HotLicks: Brilliant!

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Have you seen the overall quality of the questions posed here over the past year or so? Goodness gracious.

Comment: @HotLicks Just like when you read *primeval* you think *pre-evaluate*, and when you read *medieval* you think *mid-evaluate*. Makes sense.

Comment: How is it possible that a question can attract so many responses, yet still  have no upticks? Mysterious.

Comment: @tchrist - "Preeval" (or "pre-eval") is the obvious choice for "pre-evaluate".  And I never heard of "mid-evaluate".

Comment: @Cascabel: Currently: 6 upticks, 5 downticks.

Comment: In spite of the given reason, I think it is for "lack of research". It may be opinion, but there  are some damn fine opinions hereabouts. I am considering how to change the criteria for up/down ticks. This also affects votes on answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## In Search of Lost Etymons: Stalking Cranberry Morphemes

The learnèd word *coeval*, sometimes written *coëval* and formerly spelled *coaeval* or *coæval*, has fallen on hard times for one simple reason alone. Now that the clerical class is no longer required to study Latin, the constituent morphemes of the word are no longer accessible to them.

Because they no longer immediately know that *eval* meaning “of an age” is from Latin *aevum*, neither do they know what *coeval* means, and so it falls quickly into the forgotten desuetude all such [cranberry morphemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cranberry_morpheme) (quick! what does *cran-* mean?) are destined to die in.

The same fate has befallen *aeviternal*, *longaeval/longeval* and even *primaeval/primeval*, and even *mediaeval* and *mid-eval* have become simply *medieval* with no one having any idea why in the world we refer to the Middles Ages as “medieval”.

In short, the illatinate masses cannot automatically recover the *aevus* or *aevum* portion of these words that gave them life and meaning. To anyone with any Latin, however, all these words have an obvious meaning related to a certain age, just as *aeon* does. Notice when each of these words entered in English, per the OED:

- *aeon, eon*, n. (1581)
- *aeviternal*, adj. (1596)
- *aeviternity*, n. (1596)
- *aevum*, n. (1660)
- *eval*, adj. (1791)
- *coeval*, adj. and n. (1605)
- *coevality*, n. (1644)
- *coevally*, adv. (a1711)
- *coeve*, adj. (1659)
- *coevity*, n. (1641)
- *longeval*, adj. (1598)
- *longeve*, adj. (1678)
- *longevity*, n. (1569)
- *longevous*, adj. (1652)
- *primeval*, adj. and n. (1653)
- *primeve*, n. and adj. (1619)
- *primevity*, n. (1610)

In comparison, *medieval* from *medium aevum* is a recent borrowing that
barely showed up 200 years ago, some 200 years after those in the previous set. Back then the educated still studied Latin and Greek, so its meaning was still apparent to them. Today, they do not, and so the connections have been lost.

Interestingly, the far more commonly used word *age* ultimately derives from the same Latin 
roots as all these words do, namely *aevum* and *aevitas*, but it has suffered
the gnawing erosions [*sic*] of time until it is no longer recognizable as such.

Comment: This makes good sense.  I don't suppose it can be easily 'proved' to a moderator's satisfaction, but it seems likely to me that coeval is replaced more often by 'at the same time as' than by 'contemporaneous'.

Answer (score 3):

***Coeval*** is a useful word with [a straight-forward meaning](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coeval). Yet I have never used it.

I realise that I say ***contemporaneous*** when I might as easily say *coeval*.  Ngrams suggests that this is because [contemporaneous replaced coeval around 1840!](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=coeval%2C+contemporaneous&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccoeval%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccontemporaneous%3B%2Cc0)

Why did coeval fall out of favour?  It is attractively short but, possibly, a more daunting pronunciation challenge....?

Comment: A reason for the downvote would be interesting.

Comment: I upvoted on the strength of your having raised the possibility that the emergence of "contemporaneous" may have contributed to the demise of "coeval." I'm not sold on the one-for-one replacement theory, however. Meanwhile, "contemporaneous" has had to deal with its own challenge in recent decades: the [rise in usage of "contemporary"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=coeval%2Ccontemporaneous%2C+contemporary&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccoeval%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccontemporaneous%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccontemporary%3B%2Cc0) ...

Comment: ... including at least some instances where the evident meaning of "contemporary" is "then-current" rather than "now-current."

Comment: Downvote... possibly because you have only answered the question with "I can't say why" (since edited out) or with a question mark (currently) but no substantive and corroborated answer.

Comment: @SvenYargs - Surely *contemporary*, as a noun, can be and often is used to mean "*a person living in, or thing existing in, the same era or period as another or others*" (OED). So a school friend was my contemporary at school; we were at school contemporaneously!  Not that I'd usually say that.  I'd prefer *at the same time*.  Or even, now that I'm alerted to the word, *coevally*.

Comment: The competing use of "contemporary" that I have in mind is as an adjective in situations like this one (from Derek Offord, "[Nineteenth-Century Russian Thought and Literature](https://books.google.com/books?id=cqOCAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA123&dq=%22contemporary+thinkers%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLn7SDq9bjAhUoJjQIHbsWDYQ4WhDoAQg3MAI#v=onepage&q=%22contemporary%20thinkers%22&f=false)," in _The Routledge Companion to Russian Literature_)  (2001): "The novelists for their part, often took up and developed themes addressed by **contemporary** thinkers, as did Dostoevsky in _Crime and Punishment_ ...

Comment: ... (_Prestuplenie i nakazanie_, 1866), which carries certain **contemporary** radical ideas to what Dostoevsky sees as their logical conclusion." When I first read this sentence, I thought that perhaps Offord meant "thinkers of today" and "radical ideas of today"—but in context it appears that he meant "thinkers of Dostoevsky's time" and "radical ideas of that period." If I had been editing this piece, I would have recommended that Offord reword those two phrases as "contemporaneous thinkers" and "then-current radical ideas" to avoid potential confusion.

Comment: @SvenYargs Back when it was impossible for an educated literate person to somehow manage to be illatinate, *coëval*’s meaning was clear. Once that stopped being impossible, all direct loanwords from Latin like this one became far more bewildering and befuddling than their Germanic brethren—however wild and fuddled. :)

Comment: @tchrist: In defense of the monolingual (or semilingual) multitudes who were baffled by _coeval_, I note that we did at least resist abandoning _medieval_ in favor of _middle-aged_.